# ASP, Forms and passing variables between frames

Tags: asp-classic

I am pretty new to ASP, I know VBScript reasonably well though.  What I am trying to do is create a website with 2 frames.  In the top frame, it asks for a year (from a selection box) and a week number (from a selection box).  It should then display the dates relating to the selection and a button to process the request.  When the button is clicked the bottom form then processes a SQL query based on the selection in the top frame and displays the info.

Now, my problem is when it comes to understanding ASP.  With ASP, all the code is processed then the output is sent to the browser.  How do you update variables or even pass them to other frames when the code has already processed?

I just need some pointers on the way forward to accomplishing the above.

Thanks

Comment: You've answered your own question.  ASP is server side code, it's processed when the page loads.  You can't change a page which has already been loaded with ASP, sorry.  One way round would be to use ajax to reload a behind the scenes page which cant talk to your top frame with Javascript. Why use frames anyway, instead of your top frame you could just have an include file for your query form, and use a bit of conditional logic to get it to remember the submitted values.  I can post an example if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Listen to John. Don't give yourself headache by using frames. They deserve to be left behind in the 20th century. So skip frames and read up on Ajax and Jquery,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, don't use frames: they're annoying, ugly, and outmoded.

You can do something like this in asp, but it's going to require a round trip (or two) to the server.

The basic outline of the page (let's call it thispage.asp) would be something like

```vbs
<html><head>[head stuff]
<%
dim yr, wk, i
yr = request.form("Year")
wk = request.form("Week")
'- if you use form method='get', then use request.querystring("Year")
if not isnumeric(yr) then
   yr = Year(date)  'or whatever else you want to use as a default
else
   yr = CInt(yr)
end if
'similar validation for wk
%>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="thispage.asp">
<select name="Year" size="1">
<%
for i = Year(Date) - 2 to Year(Date) + 2
    response.write "<option value='" & i & "'"
    if i = yr then response.write " selected"
    response.write ">" & i & "</option>"
next
%>
</select> [similar code for week or date or whatever]
<input type="submit">
</form>
<%
If yr <> "" and wk <> "" Then
    '- look up stuff in database and output the desired data
    '- (this part will be much longer than this)
Else
    Response.Write "<p>Please make your selections above.</p>"
End If
%>
</body></html>
```

If you need to output form fields that are dependent on the user's initial year & week selections, then you're going to need more than one trip to the server, but it's still the same idea: set up the variables you're going to need, see if they have values, write out the form, and then if all the necessary variables have all the necessary values, then you can do your output stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of something similar.  The reason I went with frames is because I wanted to have the date selection static on the screen whereas you can scroll through the data returned from the SQL query.

Comment: @user3017424, you can do that with CSS. Frames really are not required.

Comment: Add this somewhere in one of your pages.  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll;">Lots of text here</div>

Comment: Thanks.  I have used that method many times in HTA's.  For some reason just didn't think of it here.  Anyway, thanks for the input.  I think I have a way forward now.